# C# generic list of my class contains method not finding my instance

Tags: c#, equals, contains, generic-list, iequatable

We have several classes in place for our CMS and I'm trying to get equality to work so I can check to see if a generic List contains an item. We have some layers of inheritance which I'll show you below. Below that, I'll show you some sample code that behaves contrary to my expectations. If you see something I've done wrong, please let me know. I've reduced the examples below just to show you the parts related. My actual classes are much bigger but I think this is everything you need to see.

**IBaseTemplate.cs**

```
public interface IBaseTemplate {
  bool Equals(IBaseTemplate other);
  string GUID { get; }
}
```

**BasePage.cs**

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page, IBaseTemplate, IEquatable<IBaseTemplate> {

  // code to define properties, including GUID

  // various constructors
  public BasePage(string GUID) { 
    this.GUID = GUID;
  }

  // interface methods
  public bool Equals(IBaseTemplate other) {
    return (this.GUID == other.GUID);
  }

}
```

**LandingPage.cs**

```
public class LandingPage : BasePage {
  // a bunch of extra properties and method specific to LandingPage
  // but NO definition for Equals since that's taken care of in BasePage

  public LandingPage(string GUID) : base(GUID) {}
}
```

**SamplePage.aspx.cs**

```
var p1 = new LandingPage("{3473AEF9-7382-43E2-B783-DB9B88B825C5}");
var p2 = new LandingPage("{3473AEF9-7382-43E2-B783-DB9B88B825C5}");
var p3 = new LandingPage("{3473AEF9-7382-43E2-B783-DB9B88B825C5}");
var p4 = new LandingPage("{3473AEF9-7382-43E2-B783-DB9B88B825C5}");

var coll = new List<LandingPage>();
coll.Add(p1);
coll.Add(p2);
coll.Add(p3);

p1.Equals(p4);     // True, as expected
coll.Contains(p4); // False, but I expect True here!
```

I expect `coll.Contains(p4)` to return `true` because even though `p1` through `p4` are different instances, the inherited `Equals` method from `BasePage` compares their `GUID` properties as required by `IBaseTemplate`. Did I miss something here?

I looked at the [docs for List(T)'s Contains method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and I'm implementing `IEquatable<T>.Equals` where `T` is `IBaseTemplate`.

Comment: You should be able to set a breakpoint in the Equals method to look at the values, have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `Object.Equals(Object)` as well - see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, you were spot on. I solved it in the `BasePage` with an implementation of `public override bool Equals(object obj)`

Comment: I would like to also point out that when you override Object.Equals, it is recommended that you also override GetHashCode() as well. Per documentation, "The GetHashCode method for an object must consistently return the same hash code as long as there is no modification to the object state that determines the return value of the object's Equals method." See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx for more information.

Comment: Thanks Oppositional, I had seen that warning in my output and got to that too!

Answer (score 1):

I would bet that under the covers, this line of code:

```
p1.Equals(p4)

 is actually calling upon the Equals method of `Object` rather than yours.
```

Try having your interface implement [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132154.aspx) and leave the explicit `Equals` off of your interface definition.

Comment: "The IEquatable<T> interface ... should be implemented for any object that might be stored in a generic collection." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx - IEqualityComparer is used to put a comparator on just about anything you want, not just the class you're comparing. I reckon you're right about the `Object.Equals(Object)` though.

Comment: It doesn't call `Object` Equal method, because it can find it in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Your `BasePage` type needs to implement `IEquatable<BasePage>`, and not `IEquatable<IBaseTemplate>`, if you want the [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) method to use the [`IEquatable.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190.aspx) method.

> [This method determines equality by
>   using the default equality comparer,
>   as defined by the object's
>   implementation of the
>   `IEquatable<T>.Equals` method for `T`
>   (the type of values in the list).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx)

Because your class doesn't implement `IEquatable<BasePage>`, the `Contains` method falls back to using the virtual, non-generic [`object.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) method. Overriding that method in your `BasePage` class should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

The call to [List.Contains(T item)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) *determines equality by using the default equality comparer, as defined by the object's implementation of the IEquatable.Equals method for T (the type of values in the list).*

So items to locate in the list need to provide an implementation of [IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx), and additionally need to override the [Equals(Object obj)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals.aspx) method to call into the equatable logic.

As an example, assume you have an interface like this:

```
public interface IRole : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    #region ConcurrencyToken
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the unique binary concurrency token for the security role.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// A <see cref="IList{Byte}"/> collection that contains the unique binary concurrency token for the security role.
    /// </value>
    IList<byte> ConcurrencyToken
    {
        get;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Description
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the description of the security role.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The human readable description of the security role.
    /// </value>
    string Description
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Id
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the unique identifier for the security role.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// A <see cref="Int32"/> value that represents the unique identifier for the security role.
    /// </value>
    int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region LastModifiedBy
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the user or process that last modified the security role.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The name of the user or process that last modified the security role.
    /// </value>
    string LastModifiedBy
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region LastModifiedOn
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the date and time at which the security role was last modified.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// A <see cref="Nullable{DateTime}"/> that represents the date and time at which the security role was last modified.
    /// </value>
    DateTime? LastModifiedOn
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Name
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the security role.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The human readable name of the security role.
    /// </value>
    string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

The default implementation of this interface could be this, and note how IEquatable is implemented:

```
public class Role : EntityBase, IRole, IEquatable<Role>
{
    //=======================================================================================================
    //  Constructors
    //=======================================================================================================
    #region Role()
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="Role"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public Role()
    {
    }
    #endregion

    #region Role(IEnumerable<byte> concurrencyToken)
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="Role"/> class 
    /// using the specified unique binary concurrency token.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="concurrencyToken">The unique binary concurrency token for the security role.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">The <paramref name="concurrencyToken"/> is a <see langword="null"/> reference (Nothing in Visual Basic).</exception>
    public Role(IEnumerable<byte> concurrencyToken) : base(concurrencyToken)
    {

    }
    #endregion

    //=======================================================================================================
    //  Public Methods
    //=======================================================================================================
    #region ToString()
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a <see cref="String"/> that represents the current <see cref="Role"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="String"/> that represents the current <see cref="Role"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
    #endregion

    //=======================================================================================================
    //  IEquatable<Role> Implementation
    //=======================================================================================================
    #region Equals(Role other)
    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates whether the current object is equal to another object of the same type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other">An object to compare with this object.</param>
    /// <returns><see langword="true"/> if the current object is equal to the other parameter; otherwise, <see langword="false"/>.</returns>
    public bool Equals(Role other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!String.Equals(this.Description, other.Description, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (!Int32.Equals(this.Id, other.Id))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (!String.Equals(this.Name, other.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Equals(object obj)
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the specified <see cref="Object"/> is equal to the current <see cref="Object"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The <see cref="Object"/> to compare with the current <see cref="Object"/>.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// <see langword="true"/> if the specified <see cref="Object"/> is equal to the current <see cref="Object"/>; otherwise, <see langword="false"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Equals(obj as Role);
    }
    #endregion

    #region GetHashCode()
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the hash code for this instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A 32-bit signed integer hash code.</returns>
    /// <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx"/>
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int descriptionHashCode     = this.Description.GetHashCode();
        int idHashCode              = this.Id.GetHashCode();
        int nameHashCode            = this.Name.GetHashCode();

        /*
            * The 23 and 37 are arbitrary numbers which are co-prime.
            * 
            * The benefit of the below over the XOR (^) method is that if you have a type 
            * which has two values which are frequently the same, XORing those values 
            * will always give the same result (0) whereas the above will 
            * differentiate between them unless you're very unlucky.
        */
        int hashCode    = 23;
        hashCode        = hashCode * 37 + descriptionHashCode;
        hashCode        = hashCode * 37 + idHashCode;
        hashCode        = hashCode * 37 + nameHashCode;

        return hashCode;
    }
    #endregion

    //=======================================================================================================
    //  IRole Implementation
    //=======================================================================================================
    #region Description
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the description of this security role.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The human readable description of this security role. The default value is an <see cref="String.Empty"/> string.
    /// </value>
    [DataMember()]
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return _roleDescription;
        }

        set
        {
            if (PropertyChangeNotifier.AreNotEqual(_roleDescription, value))
            {
                using (new PropertyChangeNotifier(OnPropertyChanging, OnPropertyChanged))
                {
                    _roleDescription = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? value : String.Empty;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private string _roleDescription = String.Empty;
    #endregion

    #region Id
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the unique identifier for this security role.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// A <see cref="Int32"/> value that represents the unique identifier for this security role. 
    /// The default value is <i>zero</i>.
    /// </value>
    [DataMember()]
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _roleId;
        }

        set
        {
            if (PropertyChangeNotifier.AreNotEqual(_roleId, value))
            {
                using (new PropertyChangeNotifier(OnPropertyChanging, OnPropertyChanged))
                {
                    _roleId = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private int _roleId;
    #endregion

    #region Name
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of this security role.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The human readable name of this security role. The default value is an <see cref="String.Empty"/> string.
    /// </value>
    [DataMember()]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _roleName;
        }

        set
        {
            if (PropertyChangeNotifier.AreNotEqual(_roleName, value))
            {
                using (new PropertyChangeNotifier(OnPropertyChanging, OnPropertyChanged))
                {
                    _roleName = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? value : String.Empty;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private string _roleName = String.Empty;
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to actually add the p4 instance to the collection.

```
coll.Add(p4);
```

**Edit**

Why not just compare the GUID's?

```
coll.Add(p1.GUID);
coll.Add(p2.GUID);
coll.Add(p3.GUID);
coll.Contains(p4.GUID);   //expect this to be true
```

Comment: No, I'm trying to see if anything else in the list has the same `GUID` as the `GUID` of `p4`.

Comment: Because I don't have a `List<string>` I have a `List<LandingPage>`. I've done plenty of work already to query our CMS for `List<LandingPage>` so there's no reason to re-transform that into a `List<string>` just to compare. I need to use various properties of `LandingPage`, so I need that list.